# In Blender 2.8, 3D Viewport shading render mode is missing. How do I get it back?

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, shaders

I've gotten to a state where my render option in the 3D Viewport is missing. I can render just fine using EEVEE. The screenshot is missing the camera and light, but I've added those and it makes no difference.

I've been able to use the render mode by creating a new file, and appending the old blend into that new file, but I'd really like to know how to fix it when it happens. Does anyone know what might cause this, and how to correct it?

[image: Render view option missing]

Answer (score 1):

Same thing happen to me. Try switching to LookDev and under the Lighting (drop down menu next to the Viewport Shading Button), tick Scene Lights and Scene World.

Answer (score 0):

Same happenned to me some time ago.
My guess is Blender may lose an access to the GPU and thus can't render in Viewport properly. As a proof of the theory I could see no GPUs in **Preferences > System > Cycles Render Devices**.

However, for my case it was sufficient to restart Blender.
Perhaps, it depends on the GPU problem severity.

Answer (score 0):

i got the same issue today. finally found the solution. you have to change the render engine to Eevee or Cycles except "Workbench".